# Calling the sending and email using Intent create a zoom in intent dialog

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-4.4-kitkat

**Code I used to sent an email**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        i.setType("text/plain");
                        i.putExtra(
                                Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                                new String[] { edm.getContactpersonsemail() });
                        // i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        // "subject of email");
                        // i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT , "body of email");
                        try {
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,
                                    "Send mail..."));
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    EventDetailsActivity.this,
                                    "There are no email clients installed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

**Problem I faced**

The dialog contains the sharing option became comparatively large and all the option are there, but due to a surprisingly large dialog I can't able to use it for sending email.
The image I uploaded is showing a dropbox because the dropbox is installed on the phone.
I have to drag the dialog to get the gmail icon.THE GMAIL ICON IS PRESENT IN THE DIALOG.

[image: Output in Samsung S4]

**Device Name**: Moto G, Galaxy S4

**Android O/S version**: 4.4.2

N.B. in other device with lower Android version it shows perfect.

Comment: I used "message/rfc822" suggested by @PiyushMishra, but that thing only reduces the no of choices and the problem remains same.

Comment: This sounds like dpi related. What context is being used for the `startActivity` function call? Is it your current activity?

Comment: @frozenkoi thankx for the reply yes it is the current activity.
This code is working just fine in other phones, but giving only this output in the two mentioned handsets.     
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

This is the addition I made in the manifest file.But things remain same.

Comment: I also downloaded another app from lay store which also uses that feature and this is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have "Supports Screens" tag in your manifest file remove that. Because sometimes due to this tag some particular dialog get larger then the screen in some devices.
In your case the same thing happens in S4 and Moto-G.